# Calculate limit by definition of two variables

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I am trying to calculate the following limit by definition:

$$ \lim_{ (x,y) \to (1,0)}  y*e^x = 0 $$

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: |^x−0|=|^x|<sqrt((−1)^2+(−0)^2)*|^x|<|^x| I get to this point @SagarM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should remember how to do this in single variable. For example, how would you show

$$ \lim_{x \to 2} 5x = 10 $$

What you want to show is that: For all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that if $0 < |x-2| < \delta$ then $ |5x - 10| < \epsilon $. This can be done as follows:

$$ |5x - 10| = 5|x-2| < 5\delta < \epsilon  $$

and so by choosing $\delta = \dfrac{\epsilon}{5}$ we are good.

---

Now for your case, it's a two variables so you need to show that: for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that if  $ 0 < \sqrt{(x-1)^2 + (y-0)^2} < \delta$  then  $|ye^x - 0| < \epsilon $

Also notice that: $y < \sqrt{(x-1)^2 + (y-0)^2}  $

can you take it from here?

Comment: |^x−0|=|^x|<sqrt((−1)^2+(−0)^2)*|^x|<|^x| I get to this point but I dont know how to continue.

Comment: You can bound this within some radius. Says, picking a ball of radius 1 around the point $(x,y) = (1,0)$ then what can you say about $|e^x|$?

Comment: So picking a ball of radius 1 around the point $|e^x| < e$ => $|^x| < e$ so I choose $=/e$

Comment: You got the idea but you have to be careful... The center of the ball is locating at $(x,y) = (1,0)$ so by picking the ball of radius 1, the max $x$ value is actually at 2 and not 1. Draw a picture to help you see this.

Comment: Oh. So I have to take  $e^2$ Thanks!